# Insight Into A Loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, iteration, theory

Hey I got this from StackOverflow, It counts the common values between two dictionaries but I'm hoping someone can take the time to break down the process as it's not explained in the answer section of the topic.

I think I get that;

dictionary1[key] for key in dictionary1 if key in dictionary2 and dictionary1[key] == dictionary2[key]

```
shared_items = {k: x[k] for k in x if k in y and x[k] == y[k]}
print(shared_items)
```

Does it only match where the key, value in both dictionaries match? also, why the k: at the start?

Anyway I know it's a random question but this type of iteration is really neat especially when you change the == to <= and >= it can be really useful and hopefully someone can take the time to break it down so I can wrap my head around it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as 'dict comprehension', similar to 'list comprehension'. Basically, the line

```
shared_items = {k: x[k] for k in x if k in y and x[k] == y[k]}
```

is equivalent to:

```
shared_items = {}
for k in x:
    if k in y and x[k] == y[k]:
        shared_items[k] = x[k]
```

Comment: Comprehension I couldn't even think of the word for it! Much easier to read like that. So shared_items would be an empty dict outside the for loop as shared_items = {} ?

Comment: Curious does it count the value when you state that x[k] == y[k] ...it seems to from the results I get when I switch between == >=  <=.  but value isn't referenced as v anywhere? Sorry Im such a noob!

Comment: No problem, but I don't understand your question. Can you articulate it more clearly?

Comment: Im assuming that k = key in the key, value pair. So is it just matching the key and not taking the value into account. As the two dicts I am comparing have matching keys with matching values but there are also cases where the keys match but the value is different. So does x[k] == y[k] just matches the keys or does it take the values into account and only populate shared_items with exact key, value matches or just where the key matches. Hopefully that clear enough, thanks.

Comment: First off, I don't know anything about `x` and `y`, I just stated that these two pieces of code are equivalent. If `x` is a `dict`, `k` will be a key in `x`. Also, the code `if k in y and x[k] == y[k]` doesn't make any sense. If `k` is not in `y` meaning that `y` doesn't have a key `k`, the expression `x[k] == y[k]` will throw an error. Better approach would be `if k in y and k in x and y.get(k, None) == x.get(k, None)`. This will populate `shared_dict` with exact key-value matches.